# jQuery .nextAll not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I got this html

```
<tr>
<td>
Main Alliase/Current Alliase:
</td>
<td><input type="text" id="maina" class="countchars" max="30"/><br />
    <span class="showchars"></span>
</td>
<td><span id="handle-1" class="selector" title="The Main Alliase with which people know you OR the alliase with which u play most <br /> <b>You'r App would be also named after this only</b>" header="Main Alliase/Current Alliase">?</span></td>
<td><div id="error-1" class="errors"></div></td>
</tr>
```

And this js:

```
$('#maina').focus(function() {
$(this).closest("tr").find(".selector").qtip('toggle', true);
    $(this).nextAll(".errors:first").html("Bla");
    $(this).siblings(".showchars").show();
});
```

But the when i focus into the `maina` it does the other 2 things but doesnt changes the html of `errors` class.

Why so ?
What have i been doing wrong ?
Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find(".errors:first").html("Bla");
```

Yhis is because nextAll() looks for siblings (`Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector`), and the only sibling of maina is the span

Comment: I tried this but with a little change i putted 'div' in place of 'tr'

Comment: If you use tr you are sure to get the div with class error in the same row

Comment: But why doesnt the div gives me the same result ?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/BPdRE/) `.nextAll()` only gives you back siblings.

You could use:

```
$(this).parents("tr").eq(0).find(".errors:eq(0)").html("Bla");
```